# How do I detect the start of a ajax call?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jqtouch

In JQtouch, any link is automatically convert into ajax call. I want to detect the moment the ajax call was send. This is so that i could insert a loading screen to let users know that the system is processing the submission.

I search through jqTouch API and apparently they only have callback events for page animation. Am i missing out on anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [core jQuery global AJAX functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/), for example [`$.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) for the start of a batch of requests, or [`$.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) to detect the beginning of each request.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
  alert("Request sending...");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ready up on jQuery's *Ajax Events*: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events .

You may bind these to elements as follows:

```
$("...").bind("ajaxSend",myFunction) ;
```

every element specified this way will then react to a Ajax call being made with the specified callback function.